# The selector of the component "AppFooterComponent" should be used as element

Tags: angular, tslint

The structure of my application is as follows :

```
<body>
  <header>[...]</header>
  <main>[...]</main>
  <footer><app-footer></app-footer></footer>
</body>
```

As I don't want unnecessary DOM elements, I prefer declaring `app-footer` as an attribute so I can declare the page like this :

```
<body>
  <header>[...]</header>
  <main>[...]</main>
  <footer app-footer></footer>
</body>
```

But if I do so, I get the following error message when executing `ng lint`

> The selector of the component "AppFooterComponent" should be used as element (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-03)

I think that this case is a legitimate exception to the rule. Do you agree? If so, how can I declare this specific component as an exception for this rule?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is considered a bad practice (according to the styleguide), you still can disable this specific ts lint rule for this specific component.

to do so, use /* tslint:disable:component-selector */ right before component annotation so that component declaration looks as follows:

```
/* tslint:disable:component-selector */
@Component({
    selector: '[app-footer]',
    templateUrl: './app-footer.component.html'
})
export class AppFooterComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

when you define a `@Component` angular allows to use that component as html element only. If you want to use it as an attribute on an element then make a `@Directive`

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[app-footer]'
})
export class AppFooter { 
   .....
}
```

[Doc](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)

Comment: But in this case, I won't be able to define the footer html. Do you agree?

Comment: u can define the footer element. u won't need to definte the app-footer element

Comment: Sorry @SachilaRanawaka I don't understand your last comment? What if you want the html of that element self contained with it's own CSS like a component?